# Multidimensional Smoothing spline in R

Tags: r, multiple-regression, smoothing

How create multidimensional smoothing spline for regression in R? Is there a function to implement thin-plate spline or tensor product?
I see the function ssanova() based on tensor product but I don't have a clear idea.

Comment: If your question is about computing the tensor product in R, it can be done using base R. Alternatively, have a look at the tensor package: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/tensor/versions/1.5/topics/tensor